# Why are some of potions in the shop sparkling?

Tags: slay-the-spire

Some of the potions that can be bought from the shop now have a kind of sparkling, glittering animation to them. For example, see the two leftmost potions in this picture:

[image]

I read the [release notes of the Watcher DLC](https://steamcommunity.com/games/646570/announcements/detail/1708485147042638404); it mentions that several potions now have new icons.

Is this a purely cosmetic change, or do the sparkles affect gameplay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have observed a tendency for sparkling potions to be more expensive.

The sparkles indicate the rarity of the potion. The Forge potion, which is common, does not sparkle, while the Gambler's Brew and the Distilled Chaos are both uncommon show a few moderately bright sparkles.

If there would be a rare potion for sale, like for example a Cultist potion or Entropic Brew, those would have lots of even brighter sparkles.

A potion in a shop has a **65%** (about 2 in 3) chance of being common, **25%** (or 1 in 4) of being uncommon, and **10%** (or 1 in 10) chance of being rare.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there’s no sparkly and non-sparkly version of the same potion, since it depends on rarity, which is a property of the type of potion?

Comment: @waldrumpus I'm not the one who posted the answer, but that matches my experience with previous versions of the game.

Comment: @waldrumpus correct